# Compiling Shader.... taking too much time. "Hacks" to speed it up?

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, performance, compile

[image]

This is my node tree.

I'm still working on it and, as in right now, for every node change I have to wait more than 40 seconds for the shader to recompile and it's unmotivating and extremely time consuming to work like this :/

[image]

Does anybody have any insight or knowledge on how to speed up shader compilation? Tips/workarounds (apart from disconnecting some sockets, because I wanted to see it all put together). Turning some Blender options off/on... Stuff to check? And most importantly - nodes or ways of building the node tree that should be avoided because they're more intensive? I would find a workaround for it that is less intensive then. ...Is this a node quantity thing? Or do, for example, image textures add more loading time than math nodes... something like that? There are so many ways of testing this I've tried a bit but with no specific conclusions on what's better.
Anybody got any tips?

I'm using EEVEE on Blender 4.0.2

Hardware is Intel Core i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz and a GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5)

Comment: You can bake the output of any bits of it that you consider finalized, rather than calculating everything from scratch every time.  Can't make out any nodes in your pic, so can't offer any advice more specific than that.

Comment: @Nathan hey, thanks for replying, the pic is just for a notion of the size of it. I can't bake anything because is a procedural dynamic effect. I already tried putting all repeating parts into linked duplicate nodes, not sure if that helped anything tho... (edit: sorry by bake u mean textures? or u mean u can bake node trees in general ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** The best solution I found is to use Cycles instead to visualize the changes (if the material is compatible), because Cycles actually updates the changes immediately. And even If I have to wait a few secs for the render to clear up it's always way faster than waiting a whole minute everytime in EEVEE.

I'm also probably gonna make a feature request post about the following later, that is: when I go back to EEVEE, the shader has to recompile still because it doesn't do it in the background while in Cycles, so (if it was possible), adding an option to compile the EEVEE shader behind the curtains while in Cycles would be super time saving. Even if Cycles was a little slower while it background compiled, for complex shader nodes, not having to sit still waiting a min for that white loading shader to recompile every time I change a node is still much less tiring and much much faster. This would be a good workaround for everyone building complex EEVEE shaders who feels limited because of these wait times.